# UWP package not installing for VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I am using Windows 10 and I tried installing Visual Studio 2017 Community edition with UWP package (10.0.15063.137).

I always end up with *Setup Installation failed*. I tried a complete uninstall and re-install with the help of `TotalUninstaller.exe`. I also tried the standalone Windows 10 SDK installation but nothing helps.

I am not able to create a UWP based project, nor am I getting the option for selecting Windows Universal Template in VS. Though when I tried installing VS2015, I was able to install Windows 10 SDK 10.0.14393. The problem here is I am working on solutions exported from Unity which is not opening in VS2015 as it requires updating to VS2017.

Comment: Starting with Unity 5.5 (some patch of it) it allows you to select which SDK the generated solution should target.

Comment: Can you provide any information from the setup logs about the SDK installation failure?